# In Mongo Compass, how do I fix the group stage of an accumulator object?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, mongodb-compass

I'm using Mongo Compass 1.29 on Windows 10.  I'm trying to create an aggregation pipeline to find unique values of a field in my colleciton.  The field name is "productId".  The first stage is "$unwind" and looks like

```
{
    path: '$productId',
    includeArrayIndex: 'string',
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}
```

The second stage is "$group" and is formed like so

```
{
    _id: null,
    distinctProductIds: "$productId"
}
```

but the second stage displays the error

```
The field distinctProductIds must be an accumulator object.
```

How do I fix my second stage?

Comment: `distinctProductIds: { $addToSet: "$productId" }`

Comment: Will be great if you can share sample data, as there is possible other better approach which can replace your current pipeline that use `$unwind` and `$group` stages together.

Comment: Just set `_id` with `"$productId"`: `{$group: {_id: "$productId"}}` you will get unique product ids